# Setting up Ruby CGI in Apache

Tags: ruby, apache, cgi

I want to use Ruby in Apache through CGI. I have the following in my configuration file:

```
DocumentRoot /home/ceriak/ruby

<Directory /home/ceriak/ruby>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .rb
</Directory>
```

`test.rb` is a testfile placed under `/home/ceriak/ruby/`, `#!/usr/bin/ruby` included on the first line and given executable permissions. Still, when I visit `localhost/test.rb` I get a download window and can obtain the source code.

Interestingly, when I place the same script under `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` and call `localhost/cgi-bin/test.rb` it works as supposed.

(Apache2 on Ubuntu 9.10.)

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Few things to check:

- is your file executable? You can make it executable by going `chmod +x /path/to/file`
- did you output the correct Content-type?
- is there a blank newline between your headers and your output?
- did you restart Apache after setting the configuration?

If you did all that, it should work fine. I have this as my test.rb file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts <<EOS
Content-type: text/html

<html><body>hi</body></html>
EOS
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same situation and was able to fix it by adding the following line after `AddHandler`:

```
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check that mod_cgi is enabled; the default Yosemite http.conf has it disabled.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up all of the fine advice in these answers and your question itself (I had to do every single one of these things since I was starting from a blank slate):

## httpd.conf

Set up the CGI directory with:

- The `+ExecCGI` option
- Access control that allows the visitors you want (`Require all granted`, for example)
- Set a handler for CGI scripts with `AddHandler` or `SetHandler` (see note below)

Example:

```
<Directory /home/ceriak/ruby>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .rb
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Note**: to use CGI without having to use a specific file extension like `.rb`, you can use `SetHandler` instead:

```
SetHandler cgi-script
```

Now everything in the directory will be treated as a CGI script, which is likely what you want anyway and you can leave the extensions off, which may look nicer and/or not inform visitors of the underlying technology: `http://example.com/test`

Finally, check that `mod_cgi` is enabled (where `${modpath}` is correct for your system):

```
LoadModule cgi_module ${modpath}/mod_cgi.so
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after making your changes.  On Slackware, for example, we do this:

```
$ sudo /etc/rc.d/rc.httpd restart
```

## The script

Don't forget the she-bang (`#!`) to run the script with the Ruby interpreter.

Output a `Content-type`, a newline, and then the body of your response:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Content-type: text/html"
puts
puts "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>"
```

Make sure the file is executable (by Apache!):

```
$ chmod +x /home/ceriak/ruby/test.rb
```

---

These two Apache documents are very helpful:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html