# How to run core ruby web application in web server?

Tags: ruby, apache, webserver

I had installed ruby/gem and the server is apache2 running fine.But I try to run a simple ruby project which is built by using Netbeans IDE. How can I run this web project in web browser?

Comment: Ruby is not PHP, but you can run ruby as [CGI scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245634/setting-up-ruby-cgi-in-apache), FastCGI, WSGI etc.

Answer (score 1):

While you sometimes still read that, you should not run ruby applications under CGI. The specification is getting old and support for it (especially in the rails world) is ceasing.

Most web frameworks in ruby use [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) which is a generic interface between a webserver and a ruby application. Thus if you write a rack-compliant application (which you do if you use e.g. Rails, Sinatra or Padrino) you can start it in any Webserver offering a Rack-interface.

The probbly most popular one is [Phusion Passenger (modrails)](http://modrails.com/) which is a module for either Apache or nginx and integrates into the webserver. It should be noted though that it only runs on Linux/Unix systems, not Windows.

Popular alternatives are [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) and [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/). These servers are typically run behind a front-end webserver like Apache or nginx. The frontend-webserver delivers static files (CSS, images, ...) and forwards dynamic requests to the backend-webserver (thin or unicorn). You can find many guides on google if you search for "Apache thin ubuntu" (or similar).

And as a side-note, Mongrel shouldn't be used anymore for new deployments as it isn't really maintained anymore and causes many issues with newer framework versions.

Comment: +1 for Phusion Passenger, just spend some time on figuring out how to setup and its almost magic