# process html form submission with ruby to modify local file on server

Tags: html, ruby, forms

Given the following example html form:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Sure wish I understood this. :)</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>
    <p>Enter your data:</p>
      <form method="POST" action="bar.rb" name="form_of_doom"> 
        <input type="text" name="data">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
      </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

What would "bar.rb" look like to write the submission to a text file on the server?
I am running apache, but I am trying to avoid databases and rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to invoke the Ruby file as a result of the web request, and to pass in all form data to the script.

It looks like you can do that with Apache by [treating Ruby scripts as CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245634/setting-up-ruby-cgi-in-apache). Quoting:

> ```
> DocumentRoot /home/ceriak/ruby
>
> <Directory /home/ceriak/ruby>
>     Options +ExecCGI
>     AddHandler cgi-script .rb
> </Directory>
> ```

At this point you can use the [CGI library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) that ships with Ruby to handle the parameters:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w                                                                                                           

# Get the form data
require 'cgi'
cgi = CGI.new
form_text = cgi['text']

# Append to the file
path = "/var/tmp/some.txt"
File.open(path,"a"){ |file| file.puts(form_text) }

# Send the HTML response
puts cgi.header  # content type 'text/html'
puts "<html><head><title>Doom!</title></head><body>"
puts "<h1>File Written</h1>"
puts "<p>I wrote #{path.inspect} with the contents:</p>"
puts "<pre>#{form_text.inspect}</pre>"
puts "</body></html>"
```

Comment: Myself, though, I'd go with [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) and [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) with Apache as a reverse proxy. But that's just me.

Comment: The script is not executing, it is just displaying in the browser. I made sure it was executable, but I think I am not getting Apache to obey me. I will look into Sinatra and Thin. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: See the link to the other question. Did you make the script +x, for example?